# Is there a RubyMine equivalent to emacs' Alt-/ (dabbrev-expand)?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, rubymine

I seemed to have this command working on my old machine. I could, for example, at this point type `mac<ALT-/>` and it would expand to `machine`.

However on my new machine I type ALT-/ and get a division symbol (÷).

How can I get this good behavior again?

Answer (score 0):

In emacs, `M-/`(or `ALT-/`) is binded to `hippie-expand`.

So if you have `mac|` and hit `M-/`, it tries to expand that text based on current buffer, all opened buffers. So if you have any word(s) that start with `mac`, on hitting `M-/` it will cycle through all posible completions.

If emacs doesn't find any completions it will show `No expansion found` in mini buffer.

In Your case may be some package or a piece of code has binded `M-/` to something else. You can check that by using

```
C-h k M-/
```

which shows what function is binded and where it is binded for `M-/`. Once you find it, You can remove/edit that to resume normal behaviour.

Alternatively, You can rebind it using

```
(global-set-key [(meta /)] 'hippie-expand)
```

of if you want `dabbrev-expand`

```
(global-set-key [(meta /)] 'dabbrev-expand)
```